# formGroup inside another formGroup programatically without using formArray

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, dynamicform, formgroups

I trying to add formGroup dynamically inside another formGroup without using formArray. And also add formControl in newly added formGroup dynamically.
I have also tried addFormGroup() function but its giving error that this.form.addFormGroup is not a function.

Comment: can you provide some code which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
const f = new FormGroup({});
const userGroup = new FormGroup({});
f.addControl('user', userGroup);
userGroup.addControl('firstName', new FormControl('Vladimir'));
userGroup.addControl('lastName', new FormControl('Prudnikov'));
console.log(f.value);
```

Comment: this will add form group into another form group but as a form control because of that i will not be able to use all the functions of formGroup. But thnx for help.

Comment: Isn’t it what you asked for? Adding a form group to another form group...

Comment: @paragbadala also, why you will not be able to use all the functionality of form group?